# How to store retrieves image from Facebook graph to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to store image of facebook user in `NSUserDefault` after getting retrieved from the graph api link.
This is how I'm sending the link:

```
NSString *fbuid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?", fbuid]];
```

and then with this URL I'm doing this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *stringImage = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

The to store it in user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:url forKey:@"dp"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can use this concept in multiple ways. for example

**one**

Just save the `id`in `NSUserDefaults`, where you need access that just like

```
NSString *fbuid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject: fbuid forKey:@"dp"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

**Retrieve**

// here to show in image use like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?",  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"dp"]]]];
```

**Two**
   save the `URL` String to `NSUserDefaults`,just like

```
  NSString *fbuid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
  NSString *URLStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?", fbuid]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject: URLStr forKey:@"dp"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

**Retrieve**

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?",  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"dp"]]]];
```

Comment: I just added `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] forKey:@"dp"];` and it worked :D

Comment: urs wish , we can implement in multiple ways , great day